# How to get string from value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an Customer_value column.
The column contains values like:

```
DAL123245,HC.533675,ABC.01232423
HC.3425364,ABC.045367544,DAL4346456
HC.35344,ABC.03543645754,ABC.023534454,DAL.4356433
ABC.043534553,HC.3453643,ABC.05746343
```

What I am trying to do is get the number after the first "ABC.0" string.
For example, this is what I would like to get:

1. 1232423
2. 5367544
3. 3543645754
4. 43534553
   this is what I tried:
   Substring(customer_value,charindex('ABC.', customer_value) + 5, len(customer_value)) as dataneeded

The issue that I got is for 1 and 2 I got that right data as needed, but for 3 and 4, because there are multiple ABC so it gave me everything after the first ABC.

How can I get the number after the first ABC. only?

Thank you so much

Comment: Please TAG your RDBMS.

Comment: I strongly suggest fixing your design. It appears you are breaking multiple normalisation rules here, such as storing delimited data, and that a single value represents 2 (or more) data items.

Comment: unclear: "it gave me everything after the first ABC. How can I get........ after the first ABC. only?"

Answer (score 2):

Just another option is to use a bit of JSON to parse and preserve the sequence in concert with a `CROSS APPLY`

Note: Use `OUTER APPLY` to see `NULL` values

**Example**

```
Select NewVal = replace(Value,'ABC.0','') 
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( 
                Select Top 1 *
                 From  OpenJSON( '["'+replace(string_escape(customer_value,'json'),',','","')+'"]' )
                 Where Value like 'ABC.0%'
                 Order by [key]
              ) B
```

**Results**

```
NewVal
1232423
45367544
3543645754
43534553
```

Answer (score 0):

On the assumption you are using SQL Server (given your use of *charindex()/substring()/len()*) you can use *apply* to calculate the starting position and then find the next occurence utilising the *start position* optional parameter of *charindex*, then get the substring between the values.

```
select Substring(customer_value, p1.v, Abs(p2.v-p1.v)) as dataneeded
from t
cross apply(values(charindex('ABC.', customer_value)+5))p1(v)
cross apply(values(charindex(',', customer_value,p1.v)))p2(v)
```